# Virtualbox VDI size to be increased

Tags: virtualbox

I have ubuntu installed in the orcal virtual box.
To increase vdi size i used `cloneVDI` tool and increased the vdi size from 70GB to 150GB but when i see partition using `gparted` i see extended partition exactly in the middle there is `extended` partition.[image: see the partition structure] I need suggestion in moving this extended partition to end so that i can increase `/dev/sda1` size by merging it with free space.
Any suggestion/pointers would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue, after referring ubuntu forums
i could solve it in following way,
If you dont have "ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso" downloaded, please download.

1. Shutdown virutualbox installed ubuntu.
2. Open settings of your ubuntu macine, choose virtual disc as "ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso"
3. Mark the "Live CD/DVD" option.
4. Make sure in "System" settings CD/DVD comes first int boot order.
5. Boot your virtual machine.
6. Once ubuntu boots from Live CD open terminal
7. run sudo gparted from terminal
8. Now select swap partition, rightclick and delete the paritiion. (if that doesn't work use Swap-off first and then delete the parittion).
9. Merge unallocated swap partition space with another unallocated.
10. Now change `flag` of unallocated space to `boot`.
11. Now resize `/dev/sda1`, now gparted will allow you to resize the partition.

Hope it helps someone with similar issue.